# Elasticsearch:- Error Upload Data:- Unknown error

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to upload a json file under the analytics section of Elasticsearch server and ended up with error as shown in screenshot:-

[Error Uploading data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kLxG.png)

Comment: Do you have a data example? Do you have access to Kibana and Elasticsearch logs?

Comment: Yep, i can login to elasticsearch server seems that access is already there and sample data looks like this:-     {"_index": "logs-2021.11.18","_type": "_log","_id": "Cl2KP2wBTq_AEn0ZM0t0","@timestamp": "2021-11-18T21:01:57.472Z","message": "hi"},{"_index": "logs-2021.11.18","_type": "_log","_id": "Cl2KP2wBTq_AEn0ZM0t0","@timestamp": "2021-11-18T21:01:57.472Z","message": "hi"},{"_index": "logs-2021.11.18","_type": "_log","_id": "Cl2KP2wBTq_AEn0ZM0t0","@timestamp": "2021-11-18T21:01:57.472Z","message": "hi"}

Comment: Are there any warnings or errors in Elasticsearch or Kibana logs when you run the pipeline?

Comment: Nope, it looks like ingest pipeline created step is a success as shown in screenshot here:-

Comment: Please note that i am actually uploading a static json file from my local here.

Comment: Hmm there should be some error message somehere. Do you see non-error logs in kibana and es while you're uploading? Any errors in the browser Dev Tools console?

Comment: yep, i have tried to find the browser logs and found this error:- "error": {
                        "root_cause":
                                "type": "illegal_state_exception",
                                "reason": "There are no ingest nodes in this cluster, unable to forward request to an ingest node."

Comment: How many nodes does your Elasticsearch cluster have? What roles do they have? You can see it at /_cat/nodes

Comment: I have created the elasticsearch server using AMI "bitnami-elk-7.15.2-2-linux-debian-10-x86_64-hvm-ebs-nami-ID" in AWS and have UI where i can login and provide the roles or maybe create cluster but can't do ssh in the server . so cant find /_cat/nodes. Not sure how to proceed here.

Comment: Do you have Developer Tools in Kibana? You can run arbitrary queries against Elasticsearch from there

Comment: Yep, i can see Dev-Tools in UI although i can also do ssh as well using Bitnami user insteand of ec2-user but still cant see this path /_cat/nodes present.

Comment: @ilvar Thanks for your guidance. i got a way from your idea. I have created an index using dev tools and also pushed some data in it. Afterwards, i have created an index pattern, saved it and used that in create dashboard panel. Thanks

Comment: It's an Elasticsearch endpoint not a filesystem path, see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-nodes.html You can run it from devtools like `GET /_cat/nodes?v=true`. Look into `node.role` and `master` columns, what do they have?

Comment: Happy that you got it sorted!